# Given generated base station locations, how can I generate and assign users to the nearest base stations?

Tags: matlab

This is the code in MATLAB to generate base station locations in a Voronoi tesselation but I need to generate users and to associate each user to a nearest base station.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

```
function [X Y init_n] = generate_ppp_square(params, lambda, r_total)   

%%% generate a PPP in a square of dimensions 2r*2r centered at (0,0)    
%assignparams;

lambda =0.1;
r_total =10;
cell_area = (2*r_total)^2;
init_n = poissrnd(lambda*cell_area);

%init_n = ceil(lambda*cell_area);     
%UserPoints = sqrt(cell_area)*rand(init_n,2); 
X = -r_total + 2*r_total*rand(init_n,1)
Y = -r_total + 2*r_total*rand(init_n,1)
voronoi(X,Y,'o');hold on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply generate a random set of coordinates that are within the bounds of `X` and `Y` then do a nearest neighbour search through [`knnsearch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/knnsearch.html) with only 1 output.  `knnsearch` with 1 output will return whatever is the closest data point given an input query point.  An input query point would be the position of a user.

For each user that you have, this will return the nearest base station that the user should be placed in.  Therefore, once you call the above code, it will generate 10 base stations that are found at `x` locations stored in `X` and `y` locations stored in `Y`.  We then generate some more random positions that are within these coordinates, then do a nearest neighbour search on your input points.

Let's say we want to generate 10 users in random positions.  We can use `rand` to generate a number between `[0,1)`.  Therefore, to scale a number from `[0,1)` `in` to a specified minimum and maximum value, let's call it `minX` and `maxX`, you would do:

```
out = minX + (maxX-minX)*in
```

As such, we would need to generate two sets of 10 values which are first between `[0,1)`, then scale each set so that they fit within the range of `X` and `Y` values that are within the grid of the base stations.  So you'd find the minimum and maximum `x` and `y` values, corresponding to each set of random values, then use the above equation to constrain the `(x,y)` locations.  Therefore:

```
num_users = 10;

Xq = rand(num_users,1);
Yq = rand(num_users,1);

minX = min(Xq);
maxX = max(Xq);
minY = min(Yq);
maxY = max(Yq);

Xq = minX + (maxX - minX)*Xq;
Yq = minX + (maxX - minX)*Yq;
```

Next, let's say you call the above function, and you get the locations of the base stations stored in `X` and `Y`.  Now, you'd call `knnsearch` like so:

```
IDX = knnsearch([X Y], [Xq Yq]);
```

`IDX` will give you the base number that each query point was closest to.  Therefore, let's say `IDX` was something like this:

```
IDX = 

3
4
2
1
```

The first number in `IDX` is 3, which means that the first query point was closest to the base station #3 located at `X(3)` and `Y(3)`.  Similarly, the second number is 4, meaning that the second query point was closest to base station #4, located at `X(4), Y(4)`.  How you call this function and which parameters you choose I'll leave to you because I don't really know how it's generating the base stations, but I'm assuming you know how to call this function.  Once you call the above function, use the above logic to generate users and assign them to base stations.

---

Good luck!